# VIM Pressing shift+i exits visual select mode

Tags: vim

I am trying to comment out a file lines in python. I am following the below steps for column edit mode. However, every time i press shift + I, it exits visual mode and enters Insert mode. Any suggestion

Step 1: Press Ctrl + v
Step 2: select lines using arrow keys
Step 3: Press shift + I, this quits visual mode. Note: 'r' successfully enters replace mode without exiting visual mode

Comment: What happens if you type a few characters if after you pressed shift+I and then hit escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it exits the visual mode to let you enter text at the beginning of visual selected block, I guess you want to add `#` to comment the whole block, you just type `#`, then press `ESC` you will see the selected block would be commented out.

Comment: thanks. Should have tried all the steps before posting here :/